# PHP taking user input and formatting output (dates)

Tags: php

I'm new to php and need some help, I am trying to take the user input and format it so that the output shows the last day of the month. Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
    //form for user-input
    echo "<form name='form' method='post' action='array.php'>";
    echo "<p>Enter Date in ' Month/Day/Year ' format<p>";
    echo "<input type='text' id='date-input' name='date-input' placeholder='Enter date' />";
    echo "</form>";

    //grab user-input
    $input=$_POST["date-input"];

    //output in correct format
    echo $input->format("m/t/Y");


?>
```

When I have just echo input variable without the format function and date format then it displays what the user inputs, but how it's set right now; nothing displays and I get this line:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-sessions\session-3\array.php on line 190
```

Line 190 is my echo input line.

Comment: `$input` is a string not an object. try using `echo $input;` and if you want date you may need to convert the string to date. Take a look at [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: When you say "output shows the last day of the month" does that mean you want it to output how many days are in the month provided?

Comment: Yes basically, which is why im trying to format using "t" for total days, I just want to output the number of days in the given month for what the user inputs as a date. So say the user types 2/05/2017. I want the output to display 2/28/2017 I also want it to count for leap years.

Comment: @bansi, I want to try an avoid strtotime due to the fact it will not work after year 2038

Comment: try using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). But don't forget [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) or you may get unexpected result

Comment: how would i implement DateTime and DateTimeZone with the users input? I just tried: echo new DateTime("m/t/Y",$input); but that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You may need to create a date first from your input string. Used [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $input);
echo $date->format('m/t/Y');
```

Note: Remember to use timezone parameter also with all datetime functions.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I will look up now how to implement DateTimeZone and or use parameters for timezone. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

something like replace

```
//output in correct format
    echo $input->format("m/t/Y");
```

with

```
//output in correct format
    echo date("m/d/Y",strtotime($input));
```

Comment: Just saw the edit, but I want to try and avoid strtotime due to it not working after year 2038

Comment: which means you are passing bad input. look into this sample and test it `echo $input=date('d M Y');  echo "<br />".date("m/d/Y",strtotime($input));`

Comment: Make sure month should be string (ex, Jan or January) not numeric.

Comment: I used echo     "echo <br />".input=date("m/t/Y",strtotime($input)); and it worked just like I want, but again I would like to use another method other than strtotime

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Match your requirements,

```
<?php

$date = "2040-11-23";

$Year = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $date)->format("Y");

$YearWithDay = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $date)->format(" Y-m, t \d\a\y.");

function is_leap_year($year)
{
   return ((($year % 4) == 0) && ((($year % 100) != 0) || (($year % 400) == 0)));
}

echo $YearWithDay."<br>";
echo (is_leap_year($Year))?"This Year is Leap year": "";

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2040-11, 30 day.
This Year is Leap year
```